# What Controls theme elements that impact windows and buttons?

Tags: themes

I'm confused by the relationship between Current Theme, Cursor theme, Icon Theme and gtk+ theme. For example choosing the Adwaita theme gives me a darkened panel at top of screen/notification area but makes my dialog boxes have "ridges" and a early Linux/Windows 3.0 look.

[image]

I have tried to manipulate via the Advanced Tweak tool but with unexpected results. Is there a better tool to use? any tips on making this work better are appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a short summary;

1. **Current Theme** (as it is now called in Gnome's **Tweak Tool**) is not a good name for **Window Manager / Metacity Theme**, which controls borders/decorations (including titlebars and buttons) of almost all windows of applications, dialog boxes, etc.
2. **Cursor Theme** only controls the shape and color of the cursor as seen in various mouse movements and statuses.
3. **Icon Theme** controls all the icons you see in file managers, Unity Dash, Launcher and Panel (folders, files, applications, etc.), and in most applications (but not all).
4. **GTK+ Theme** controls all the other decorations inside window borders, including toolbars, menubars, tabs, etc.) and also the Unity panel at the top.

You will have a better appearance if you choose **ubuntu-mono-dark/light** icon theme instead of Unity icon theme seen in your screenshot (which shouldn't be listed at all, I think). As you know **Ubuntu default theme** (both window and gtk) is **Ambiance**.

But you can get many other themes as well. You should only make sure they are compatible with your system, especially Gnome **3.6** as many things have changed recently.